# if else in transaction query giving weird output

Tags: vb.net, transactions

Below is my code for updating items in a invoice. 
I add some items and update some items based on values but it is just inserting or updating the same values to all the rows. I think the paramerters are creating the problem, please guide me to rectify the fault.

```
        con.Open()
        tra = con.BeginTransaction
        sqlstr = "UPDATE transaction_Mas_Tab set billdate=@billdate,invoiceno=@invoiceno,TotalBillamt=@TotalBillamt,narration=@narration,orderdate=@orderdate,usercode=@usercode,lcode=@lcode,remarks=@remarks,grossamt=@grossamt where txid=@txid "
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(sqlstr, con, tra)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@billdate", dtpbilldate.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@invoiceno", txtinvoiceno.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalBillamt", Val(txtgt.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@narration", txtnote.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orderdate", dtpbilldate.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usercode", usercode)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lcode", cmbparty.SelectedValue)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@remarks", txtrmrks.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@grossamt", Val(txttotalamt.Text))
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txid", txid)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()     
        For c As Integer = 0 To dgvsitemlist.Rows.Count - 1
            If dgvsitemlist.Rows(c).Cells("onew").Value.ToString = "N" And dgvsitemlist.Rows(c).Cells("isdel").Value.ToString = "N" Then
                sqlstr = "insert into transaction_details (txid,itemid,unit,irate,iqty,isdeleted)  values(@txid,@itemid,@unit,@irate,@iqty,@isdeleted)"
                cmd = New OleDbCommand(sqlstr, con, tra)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txid", txxid)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemid", dgvsitemlist.Rows(c).Cells("itemid").Value.ToString)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@unit", dgvsitemlist.Rows(c).Cells("unitid").Value.ToString)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@irate", Val(dgvsitemlist.Rows(c).Cells("prate").Value))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iqty", Val(dgvsitemlist.Rows(c).Cells("qty").Value))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isdeleted", "N")
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                sqlstr = "INSERT INTO IMasterDetails ( icode,batch,prate,srate,opstock,clstock,pscheme,sscheme,itemid) values (  @icode ,@batch , @prate , @srate,@opstock,@clstock,@pscheme,@sscheme,@itemid )"
                cmd = New OleDbCommand(sqlstr, con, tra)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@icode", dgvsitemlist.Rows(c).Cells("icode").Value.ToString)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@batch", dgvsitemlist.Rows(c).Cells("batch").Value.ToString)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prate", Val(dgvsitemlist.Rows(c).Cells("prate").Value))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@srate", Val(dgvsitemlist.Rows(c).Cells("srate").Value))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@opstock", Val(dgvsitemlist.Rows(c).Cells("qty").Value))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clstock", Val(dgvsitemlist.Rows(c).Cells("qty").Value))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pscheme", dgvsitemlist.Rows(c).Cells("pscheme").Value.ToString)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sscheme", dgvsitemlist.Rows(c).Cells("sscheme").Value.ToString)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemid", dgvsitemlist.Rows(c).Cells("itemid").Value.ToString)

            ElseIf dgvsitemlist.Rows(c).Cells("onew").Value.ToString = "O" And dgvsitemlist.Rows(c).Cells("isdel").Value.ToString = "N" Then
                sqlstr = "update transaction_details set itemid=@itemid,unit=@unit,irate=@irate,iqty=@iqty,isdeleted=@isdeleted where txid=@txid"
                cmd = New OleDbCommand(sqlstr, con, tra)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemid", dgvsitemlist.Rows(c).Cells("itemid").Value.ToString)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@unit", dgvsitemlist.Rows(c).Cells("unitid").Value.ToString)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@irate", Val(dgvsitemlist.Rows(c).Cells("prate").Value))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iqty", Val(dgvsitemlist.Rows(c).Cells("qty").Value))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isdeleted", "N")
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txid", txxid)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                sqlstr = "Update IMasterDetails set icode=@icode,batch=@batch,prate=@prate,srate=@srate,opstock=@opstock,clstock=@clstock,pscheme=@pscheme,sscheme=@sscheme where itemid=@itemid "
                cmd = New OleDbCommand(sqlstr, con, tra)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@icode", dgvsitemlist.Rows(c).Cells("icode").Value.ToString)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@batch", dgvsitemlist.Rows(c).Cells("batch").Value.ToString)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prate", Val(dgvsitemlist.Rows(c).Cells("prate").Value))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@srate", Val(dgvsitemlist.Rows(c).Cells("srate").Value))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@opstock", Val(dgvsitemlist.Rows(c).Cells("qty").Value))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clstock", Val(dgvsitemlist.Rows(c).Cells("qty").Value))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pscheme", dgvsitemlist.Rows(c).Cells("pscheme").Value.ToString)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sscheme", dgvsitemlist.Rows(c).Cells("sscheme").Value.ToString)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemid", dgvsitemlist.Rows(c).Cells("itemid").Value.ToString)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            ElseIf dgvsitemlist.Rows(c).Cells("onew").Value.ToString = "O" And dgvsitemlist.Rows(c).Cells("isdel").Value.ToString = "Y" Then
                sqlstr = "update transaction_details set itemid=@itemid,unit=@unit,irate=@irate,iqty=@iqty,isdeleted=@isdeleted where txid=@txid"
                cmd = New OleDbCommand(sqlstr, con, tra)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemid", dgvsitemlist.Rows(c).Cells("itemid").Value.ToString)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@unit", dgvsitemlist.Rows(c).Cells("unitid").Value.ToString)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@irate", Val(dgvsitemlist.Rows(c).Cells("prate").Value))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iqty", Val(dgvsitemlist.Rows(c).Cells("qty").Value))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isdeleted", "Y")
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txid", txxid)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End If
        Next

        tra.Commit()
        updatebilldata = txid
        clearall()
        clearsave()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Some thing Went Wrong")
        tra.Rollback()
        updatebilldata = Nothing
    End Try
End Using
```

Comment: Try adding `cmd.Parameters.Clear()` after each `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`. Since you are using `New` each time, this *shouldn't* be necessary, but given your symptoms I'd say it's worth a shot.

Comment: In the updates, the WHERE clause value is using txxid, but I do not see anywhere that this value is changing.   That might be causing the issue that you are experiencing.

Comment: You're missing a ExecuteNonQuery after the IMasterDetails. All of your update using txxid will be overwritted since txxid doesn't change for each rows. Also, you should think of renaming that "c" variable for rowIndex or something. Maybe turn option strict on? You might see if txxid is being initialized or not.